# What's the correct approach to evaluate a model using K-fold cross validation over multiple seeds?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cross-validation

I am training a deep learning model using a 5-fold CV over three random seeds (random seeds are for model initialization, CV is split once). For each fold, I save the best model. Hence, I get 15 models after the simulation. To assess the performance, I take the best of these 15 models (unchanged during the entire evaluation process) and evaluate it using the validation fold of all the 5-folds for each seed. I then average the results across these seeds.

I would like to know if I am doing the right thing here.

I have read that there are two ways to compute CV performance: [1] pooling, where the performance is calculated globally over the union of all the test sets [2] averaging, where the performance is computed for every test set separately, with results being the average of these.

I intend to use method two (averaging).

Comment: To clarify: by 'three random seeds' do you mean, different random initializations of your deep learning model, or different ways to split your 5-fold CV set. I think you mean the former, but not 100% clear.

Comment: Yes please, 3 random initializations of the deep learning model. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the averaging method for the 5-fold CV, but I don't understand what you mean by "For each fold, I save the best model". Moreover, three random seed values are not enough. You should use at least 10 different values and plot a boxplot for the corresponding results across these seeds.